# Lower bound on minimal eigenvalue of $B(A+B)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

Matrix $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive semidefinite. I wish to lower bound the minimal eigenvalue of the matrix product:

$$B(A+B)^{-1}A$$

The first lower bound I came up with is:

$$\lambda_{\min} \left( B (A+B)^{-1} A \right) \geq \frac{\lambda_{\min}(A) \cdot \lambda_{\min}(B)}{\lambda_{\max}(A+B)}\geq\frac{\lambda_{\min}(A) \cdot \lambda_{\min}(B)}{\lambda_{\max}(A)+\lambda_{\max}(B)}$$

According to this lower bound, if we do rank-one update on $A$ and $B$ in such a way that $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ and $\lambda_{min}(B)$ remain the same, but $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(B)$ increase (by updating A and B using eigenvectors corresponding to their maximum eigenvalues), then the lower bound will decrease.

However, my simulation results show that the minimum eigenvalue of this matrix product actually always increases as I rank-one updating $A$ and $B$.

Then my question is, whether there is any tighter lower bound of the minimum eigenvalue of this product?

Comment: You assume that $A+B>0$. Show that i) $B(A+B)^{-1}A$ is symmetric, ii) the eigenvalues of $B(A+B)^{-1}A$ are $\geq 0$ and iii)  your first inequality.

Comment: Moreover, if $A$ or $B$ is not $>0$, then  the minimal eigenvalue is $0$. Have you really thought about this problem?

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks for your comment! What do you mean by the three steps?

Comment: So far you haven't shown anything. So it would be good if you could prove the $3$ above points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

To lower bound the minimum eigenvalue, we need the following result.
$$B(A+B)^{-1}A=(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$$
Then it directly leads to:
$$\lambda_{\min} \left( B (A+B)^{-1} A \right) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{max}(A^{-1}+B^{-1})}\geq \frac{1}{\lambda_{max}(A^{-1})+\lambda_{max}(B^{-1})}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A)}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(B)}}$$

To show that $B(A+B)^{-1}A=(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$, we start from:
$$A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}=A^{-1}AB^{-1}+A^{-1}BB^{-1}=B^{-1}+A^{-1}$$
Then taking inverse of both sides gives the result.